# aspx TextBox not displaying html characters

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application which has a TextBox:

```
asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control monospace" ID="SKEDescriptionTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Text='<%# Bind("SKEDescription")%>'  />"
```

It is bound to a field SKEDescription which is derived from an old mainframe application and is simply text - with no formatting. (old green screen stuff)

Within the web app, the user can change this TextBox and the resultant text gets sent back to the mainframe - after a large amount of code to strip formatting and other characters which will upset the mainframe.

However, if the user enters any text which even looks like HTML (e.g. ) then the code fails even before it enters the checking code. This was solved by adding

```
ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"
```

to the TextBox asp: line.

So now the user can enter  and it is successfully sent to the mainframe,

BUT when the screen is redisplayed all the new text is displayed EXCEPT  - it is not there.

Is there another method/property of TextBox that controls what is displayed from the Bind source rather than the user input?

And as an aside this textbox I am typing into to describe the problem has exactly the same issue - I originally entered the code snippet at the top starting with the less than sign and the snippet was removed only the final /> was visible. Editing this box and removing the initial sign and the whole snippet appears by magic.!!!

Comment: Note the text description of the problem exhibits the problem. So in the text above I say "looks like HTML (e.g.  ) " is what actually appears, but I actually typed some text after the e.g. - however this text started with a less-than sign and ended with a greater-than sign. So the code behind this TextBox removed it and it does not display!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

As with this Stack Overflow page my page actually had two TextBox controls that occupied the same area of screen depending on whether the screen was in display mode or edit mode.
The snippet in the original post above showed the Edit TextBox. The Display control was

asp:Literal ID="litSKEDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SKEDescription") %>'  />

The addition of Mode= "Encode" to this snippet enables (apparent) html text to be displayed